# How to store values in a function and be printed/modified from another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to create a function that has different types of enemies in it. But I do not know the amount of enemies, they will be randomly generated. Then, I want to print them out by having an input statement saying press 1 for the first enemy, 2 for the second, etc. So it'd be like, you got 3 zombies, 15 ghosts, etc But, I want it to be created in a way that I can later on add more inputs so that the user can modify it, like 'which type of enemy do you want to add/delete enemies from?. I need help on how to do this, please. Here's what I got so far, if my code can be modified to be simpler, make more sense, in a way I can learn it and understand, that'd be perfect, thanks!

```
import random
def fillEnemyField():
    print("Here's your first EnemyField")
    zombies = []
    zombies = random.randrange(0, 15)
    trolls = []
    trolls = random.randrange(0, 15)
    vampires = []
    vampires = random.randrange(0, 15)
    ghosts = []
    ghosts = random.randrange(0, 15)

def printEnemyField():
    choice1 = int(input("Press 1 to get a new EnemyField"))
    choice2 = int(input("Press 2 to get a new EnemyField"))
    choice3 = int(input("Press 3 to get a new EnemyField"))
    choice4 = int(input("Press 4 to get a new EnemyField"))
    choice5 = int(input("Press 5 to quit"))
    while choice != 5:
        if choice ==1:
            choice = print(fillEnemyField(zombies))
    ..............................
```

Comment: your function `fillEnemyField()` isn't returning something. So, you should print it.

Comment: I do want to ask, where is the variable `choice` defined? Running the code returns an error for this, and I wouldn't expect it not to.

Comment: @NaruS see, that's something I was trying to do, have ONE input but that asks 4 times but it says press 1 press 2 press 3 without having to create different choices. Is that even possible? If so how?

Comment: @MatheusReis that's what I do not know what to do, I don't know which one to return since there are several values

Comment: A string like `Enemies on field: Zombies: X Trolls: Y Vampires: Z Ghosts: K` would be enough for you?

Comment: @MatheusReis what does that do? Sorry I'm just now learning

Comment: It was just an ideia of what your function could return. Ignore it.. The @ktzr solution seems to be proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function isn't returning anything, you could return a dictionary and from that later choose what value you want, for example:

Also, make sure to update choice in the while loop, or else you will be stuck in the loop forever.

```
import random
def fillEnemyField():
    print("Here's your first EnemyField")
    return {"zombies": random.randrange(0, 15),
            "trolls": random.randrange(0, 15),
            "vampires": random.randrange(0, 15),
            "ghosts": random.randrange(0, 15)
            }

def printEnemyField():
    print("Press 1 to get a new EnemyField")
    print("Press 2 to get a new EnemyField")
    print("Press 3 to get a new EnemyField")
    print("Press 4 to get a new EnemyField")
    print("Press 5 to quit")
    choice = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    while choice != 5:
        if choice ==1:
            print(fillEnemyField()['zombies'], "zombies in the field")
        choice = int(input("Enter a number: "))

printEnemyField()
```

**Or**

What is probily a better option, you can pass the choice in as an argument and then return that choise, for example:

```
def fillEnemyField(choise):
    print("Here's your first EnemyField")
    options = {"zombies": random.randrange(0, 15),
               "trolls": random.randrange(0, 15),
               "vampires": random.randrange(0, 15),
               "ghosts": random.randrange(0, 15)
               }
    return options[choise]


def printEnemyField():
    ...
    choice = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    while choice != 5:
        if choice == 1:
            print(fillEnemyField('zombies'), "enemies on the field")
        choice = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Comment: What if I the user chose that he wanted to add +3 zombies without randomizing the choices? or take away 3?

Comment: you would store the output of `fillEnemyField('zombies')` in a variable, eg `enemies = fillEnemyField('zombies')`, and based on user response increment or decrement it, eg `enemies += 3`, you would also want to check you aren't going below 0 eg `if enemies < 3: print("you cant remove 3 enemies")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import random

def fillEnemyField():
      # Define enemy amounts
      zombies = random.randrange(0, 15)
      trolls = random.randrange(0, 15)
      vampires = random.randrange(0, 15)
      ghosts = random.randrange(0, 15)

      # return enemy amounts so you can use them later
      # if you don't care about these names, you could do something like this
      # return [random.randrange(0, 15), random.randrange(0, 15), random.randrange(0, 15), random.randrange(0, 15]
      return [zombies, trolls, vampires, ghosts]

def printEnemyField():
    # when you do something multiple times, it's cleaner to use a loop
    for x in range(4):
        # this is formating a string, here is a great guide on this
        # https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-us-string-formatters-in-python-3
        print("Press {} to get a new EnemyField".format(x+1))
    print("Press 5 to quit") # this print is differnt, so we won't use it in the loop

    fields = fillEnemyField() # get all those enemies we worked so hard to make

    choice = int(input()) # get input from the user
    while choice != 5: # we want to quit on 5
        print(fields[choice-1]) # here we print out the ith value of the array, remember to subract 1 because arrays start at 0
        choice = int(input()) # get more input from the user so our loop doesn't just print forever

printEnemyField() # remember to call your functions from somewhere, otherwise it wont get run
```